# Toggle breakpoints on custom editor in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I want to toggle breakpoints on a new editor I created. I have a new editor and a new LineBreakpoint implemented and running. I can already toggle these breakpoints with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> or Main Menu -> Run -> Toggle Line Breakpoint. I want to be able to add to the vertical ruler bar of my custom eclipse application the very same toggle behavior in the Java Editor. That is, double click creates/toggles a breakpoint at a given line location. And right click brings up the toggle breakpoint menu context (on the vertical ruler bar). Complete with the line toggle image label too.

*I'm assuming there is an easy way to do this*, as opposed to implement each menu and action. If not, how do I add these double click and context menus to the a custom editor's vertical ruler?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into doing the same thing. So far I have found that extending AbstractDecoratedTextEditor will give you the platform to do this. I will update when I have it working.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but I had this problem and did this:

I have a editor (org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor). On this editor class I implemented this method:

```
@Override
protected IVerticalRulerColumn createAnnotationRulerColumn(CompositeRuler ruler) {
    AnnotationRulerColumn column = new MyAnnotationRulerColumn(VERTICAL_RULER_WIDTH, getAnnotationAccess(), this);
    return column;
}
```

And the class MyAnnotationRulerColumn is some think like that:

```
import org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.ToggleBreakpointAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.AnnotationRulerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.IAnnotationAccess;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.IVerticalRulerInfo;

public class MyAnnotationRulerColumn extends AnnotationRulerColumn {

    private MyEditor editor;

    public MyAnnotationRulerColumn(int width, IAnnotationAccess annotationAccess, MyEditor part) {
        super(width, annotationAccess);
        this.editor = part;
    }

    @Override
    protected void mouseDoubleClicked(int rulerLine) {
        if (editor != null) {
            IVerticalRulerInfo rulerInfo= (IVerticalRulerInfo) editor.getAdapter(IVerticalRulerInfo.class);
            ToggleBreakpointAction action = new ToggleBreakpointAction(editor, null, rulerInfo);
            action.update();
            action.run();
        }
    }

}
```